# How to type my component props from a trpc type

Tags: reactjs, trpc

I'm experimenting with a React Native + React Query and tRPC + Prisma setup and finding some **problems with the typo workflow between tRPC and react**

I'm querying my data on one screen

```js
  const { data: highline, isFetchedAfterMount } = trpc.highline.getById.useQuery(
    highlitedMarker.id
  );
```

and then navigating to a details screen that receives the data `highline` as props

```js
navigation.navigate('Details', { highline });
```

To type this parameter I'm doing

```
highline: RouterOutput['highline']['createHighline'];
```

but `highline` get the type of `Highline | undefined`. Is this the correct way of doing this inference? I want `highline` to be typed specifically `Highline`

Answer (score 0):

Which highline?
The **data highline** from trpc query?

Let's see what `trpc.highline.getById.useQuery` return as data.

I assume you're using prisma findUnique which returns null (undefined) if not found.

You can try [Output Validation](https://trpc.io/docs/server/output-validation) or simply handling the undefined highline before navigating in the client side.

The **highline parameter** for details screen should be inferred just okay with your method. If it is inferred then typescript should raise an error because of the possible undefined from data highline.